# How to enhance quiz game for multiple choice?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am not sure how I should create this as a "multiple choice" quiz game.

I don't know how to continue on. I am not sure how to use class in this instance. If I can get the first question working with answers, I'm sure I am continue on from there but I am in need of help.

Here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


#User Interface Code

root = Tk() # Creates the window
root.title("Quiz Game")

def new_window():
   newWindow = Toplevel()
   message = Label(newWindow, text="What is the capital of France?", font = 
   ("Arial", "24"), pady=30)
   display = Label(newWindow, width=150, height=40)

   class letsQuiz:
      def __init__(self, questions, answers):
         self.questions = questions
         self.answers = answers

         self.label = Label(newWindow, text="What is the capital of France?")
         self.label.pack()

         self.answer1button = Button(newWindow, text="Madrid")
         self.answer2button = Button(newWindow, text="Paris")
         self.answer3button = button(newWindow, text="London")

         self.answer1button.pack()
         self.answer2button.pack()
         self.answer3button.pack()

   message.pack()
   display.pack()

message_label1 = Label(text="Let's quiz some of your knowledge :)", font = ( 
"Arial", "25"), padx=40, pady=20)
message_label2 = Label(root, text="Click 'Continue' to begin.", 
wraplength=250)
button1 = Button(root, text ="Continue", command=new_window, width=16, 
bg="red")
display2 = Label(root, width=100, height=30)

message_label1.pack()
message_label2.pack()
button1.pack()
display2.pack()

root.mainloop() # Runs the main window loop
```

Comment: Looks like you fixed your "Question One" being at the bottom of the window. And didn't accept that as answer xD

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new here. Don't know how things work. Sorry, my bad man. I'll accept your answer!

Comment: I'll work on a example and post a solution in few mins.

Comment: Good. but for the record: "please help me" isnt a request in the scope of this community. To be more in line with the policies of this community, you should try to first solve this yourself. And then when you are stuck on your way, with specific problems, then you should ask a question about that. Putting down requirements, and some code and then: now tell me how to bring these two things together ... is as as said: not a good idea.

Comment: Understandable. I'll be more in-line with the community rules and guidelines. This issue has been bothering me for while now, I tried solving it myself but failed so I'm going to try ask questions here,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go, This should set you up with a good base to work on. I've added few comments to help you out. I've kept most your code intact so you can understand easily. Note that this is no where an optimal way to code a good quiz game. But okay if you're starting on it.
Scoring can be done using lot of if statements and instance variables to keep track of. Good luck !

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#User Interface Code

root = Tk() # Creates the window
root.title("Quiz Game")


def new_window():
   newWindow = Toplevel()
   message = Label(newWindow, font = 
   ("Arial", "24"), pady=30)
   display = Label(newWindow, width=150, height=40)
   return newWindow

class letsQuiz:

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.newWindow = window

        self.question_counter = 0


        # Add your questions and answers here
        self.questions = ['# QUESTION: 1', '# QUESTION: 2', '# QUESTION: 3', '# QUESTION: 4']
        # Each list is a set of answers corresponding to question
        self.answers = [['question_1_Answer_1', 'question_1_Answer_2', 'question_1_Answer_3'], 
                        ['question_2_Answer_1', 'question_2_Answer_2', 'question_2_Answer_3'],
                        ['question_3_Answer_1', 'question_3_Answer_2', 'question_3_Answer_3'],
                        ['question_4_Answer_1', 'question_4_Answer_2', 'question_4_Answer_3']]

        self.label = Label(self.newWindow, text=self.questions[self.question_counter], font = 
        ("Arial", "24"), pady=30)


        self.answer1button = Button(self.newWindow, text=self.answers[self.question_counter][0])
        self.answer2button = Button(self.newWindow, text=self.answers[self.question_counter][1])
        self.answer3button = Button(self.newWindow, text=self.answers[self.question_counter][2])

        self.nextButton = Button(self.newWindow, text="Next", command=self.next_question)

    def pack_all(self):
        '''
        Packs all widgets into the window
        '''
        self.label.pack()

        self.answer1button.pack()
        self.answer2button.pack()
        self.answer3button.pack()

        self.nextButton.pack()

    def forget_all(self):
        '''
        Removes all widgets from the window
        '''
        self.label.pack_forget()

        self.answer1button.pack_forget()
        self.answer2button.pack_forget()
        self.answer3button.pack_forget()

        self.nextButton.pack_forget()


    def next_question(self):
        '''
        Updates the question and its corresponding answers
        '''
        self.question_counter += 1

        self.forget_all() # remove old question 


        try:

            self.label = Label(self.newWindow, text=self.questions[self.question_counter], font = 
            ("Arial", "24"), pady=30)


            self.answer1button = Button(self.newWindow, text=self.answers[self.question_counter][0])
            self.answer2button = Button(self.newWindow, text=self.answers[self.question_counter][1])
            self.answer3button = Button(self.newWindow, text=self.answers[self.question_counter][2])

            self.nextButton = Button(self.newWindow, text="Next", command=self.next_question)
        except IndexError:
            self.forget_all()
            msg = Label(self.newWindow, text="You have completed the quiz Thank you for playing, Close to EXIT", font = 
            ("Arial", "24"), pady=30)
            msg.pack()




        self.pack_all() # place in the new question    

quiz = letsQuiz(new_window() )

#message.pack()
#display.pack()

message_label1 = Label(text="Let's quiz some of your knowledge :)", font = ( 
"Arial", "25"), padx=40, pady=20)
message_label2 = Label(root, text="Click 'Continue' to begin.", 
wraplength=250)
button1 = Button(root, text ="Continue", command=quiz.pack_all, width=16, 
bg="red")
display2 = Label(root, width=100, height=30)

message_label1.pack()
message_label2.pack()
button1.pack()
display2.pack()

root.mainloop() # Runs the main window loop
```

Comment: Let me know if you run into some issue

Comment: Alright! I will use this as a basis! This will give me a start off. Thanks man!

Comment: Hey Vineeth, I've started off with your basis but I have run into an issue where it has said,

"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: new_window() missing 1 required positional argument: 'question'"

Comment: Okay I've edited the code to remove question parameter from new_window(). Do check :)

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your reply. If I remove the parameter from the new_window(), it says, 

    message = Label(newWindow, text=question, font = ("Arial", "24"), pady=30)
NameError: name 'question' is not defined
>>>. I'll find my way around this and ask again if I need further help.

Comment: I think it's because I may have the class inside the function def new_window().

Comment: In that case pass self as parameter into the new_window function. That should fix the problem :)

Comment: Just like other functions in the class.

Comment: Hey again, no still doesn't work. I haven't exactly copied your code but it is similar and it's obviously the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: `www.pastebin.com`, then paste the generated link here

Comment: Here, I've changed few errors you made. And still there are some left which you should be able to fix by yourself :)
https://pastebin.com/JdsyVJR0

Comment: This has fixed my issue! This is exactly how I want it. Thank you. I'll message you when I run into more issues.

Comment: Sure no problem :)

Comment: Hey man, this issue has been doing my head in. The error says "line 51, in __init__
    self.label_forget()
AttributeError: 'letsQuiz' object has no attribute 'label_forget'"